# Unable to run scala on Windows

Tags: windows, scala, intellij-idea

I have the latest `Intelliji Idea` and i have installed Scala plugin. If needed Java version:
`java version "14.0.1" 2020-04-14`
`Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 14.0.1+7)`
`Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 14.0.1+7, mixed mode, sharing)`
When I write `scala` in terminal, it says `scala not recognized`

1. I just create `test.scala` and i cannot run it(run label is unable). Is that correct way to do that?
2. I crate a project, chose `sbt`( which i still understanding what is it  and why i have/need to choose it). Appeared `Scala REPL`, but i don't think it is what I want.
3. Am I able just to run `Scala` file like `Java` file and get a result in terminal in IDEA?
4. As i understand, `Scala` and `sbt` like `Java` and `Maven/Gradle`? 
   P.S. As a very newbie, am I missing something vital before starting `Scala`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Intellij can use (and by default uses) its own distribution of `sbt` - the fact that it can build sbt projects doesn't mean that there is a global sbt installation available.

sbt in turn also uses its own version of `scala` and `scalac`, so the fact that you can run sbt doesn't mean that there is a global installation of `scala` and `scalac`.

So, the fact that you installed Scala plugin to Intellij Idea doesn't make `scala` and `scalac` available in your global `PATH` where shell can run it. If you want to have them here, install Scala using your package manager (in windows there is [winget](https://github.com/microsoft/winget-cli) or [chocolatey](https://chocolatey.org/)) or [sdkman](https://sdkman.io/) (if you use Cygwin) or using MSI installer (e.g. https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.13.3/scala-2.13.3.msi).